# Getting the sum of fields made numeric with regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, regexp-replace

In Oracle I need to get a sum of numbers from a string field.  These numbers may include a ..  I've tried the following query:

```sql
SELECT line_id, SUM(footage)
  FROM (SELECT line_id,
               CASE
                 WHEN footage IS NULL THEN
                  0
                 ELSE
                  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(footage, '[^0-9.]+', ''))
               END AS footage
          FROM pipe)
 GROUP BY service_line_id
```

This gives an error on the REGEXP_REPLACE that it is an invalid number.  It works if I leave out the decimal point, but I really need to include it.  How do I get the sum with the decimal point included in the regular expression?

Comment: Please include sample data that generates the error. What are is your session NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting? You might just need to specify that in the `to_number()` call, using the optional third parameter. But there could be something else wrong with the values.

Comment: Your query will fail as the outer query groups by `service_line_id` but there is no `service_line_id` selected in the inner sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can leave multiple full stop characters which will result in an invalid number. Instead of trying to replace the non-number characters, you can try to match the decimal using:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(footage, '\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+')
```

Then you can simplify the query to:

```sql
SELECT line_id,
       SUM(COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(footage, '\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+')), 0))
         AS footage
FROM   pipe
GROUP BY line_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pipe (line_id, footage) AS
SELECT 1, '42 is an integer.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A decimal is like 2.5.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Some decimals, like .32 do not have an integer part.' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | LINE_ID | FOOTAGE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 44.82 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a080cfac417329832efc9a742c0457ec)*